# How to get the starting month based on ID's

Tags: sas

```
Id jan feb mar apr may jun jul
A  1   .  .     1  1    .  .
B .    .  1     .   .   .  .
A .   1   .    .    .   .  .
C .    .  .     1   .   .  .
```

I want to know which is starting month where the value is not missing.
For A it is jan, for B it is mar ans so on.

Comment: Please include what you've tried in your question as per SO rules.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the part of your question where you said NOT MISSING.  That requires another function coalesce to find the value of the first non-missing.

```
data id;
    input Id:$1. jan feb mar apr may jun jul;
    array a[*] jan-numeric-jul;
    target = coalesce(of a[*]);
    l=whichn(target,of a[*]);
    if l gt 0 then month = vname(a[l]);
    cards;
A  1   .  .     1  1    .  .
B .    .  99     .   .   .  .
A .   223   .    .    .   .  .
C .    .  .     -11   .   .  .
;;;;
    run;
proc print;
    run;
```

You need an ARRAY and a couple of functions.

```
data id;
    input Id:$1. jan feb mar apr may jun jul;
    array a[*] jan-numeric-jul;
    month = vname(a[whichn(1,of a[*])]);
    cards;
A  1   .  .     1  1    .  .
B .    .  1     .   .   .  .
A .   1   .    .    .   .  .
C .    .  .     1   .   .  .
;;;;
    run;
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having 28 months and i'm using the above code and getting error "array subscript out of range"?

Comment: data a;
input id$ ap14 mar14 jun14 jul14 aug14 sep14 oct14 nov14 dec14 jan15 feb15 mar15 ap15 may15 jun15 jul15 sep15 oct15 nov15 dec15
      jan16 feb16 mar16 ap16 may16 jun16 jul16 aug16;
   array a[*] ap14-numeric-aug16;
   x=whichn(1,of a[*]);
   cards;
0028545 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  2
;run;

Comment: so this is the data and the solution is not working on this. Here the value of x is coming zero instead of the column number Please let me know the reason..

Comment: @Anonamous please see my addition to the answer.  I missed part of the requirement.